# how to link svg images without dissapear?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to link my svg images but once i add the  tag they dissapear.

HTML - with this code they are showing

```
<section class="contact" id="contact">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="assets/images/gmail.svg" alt="">
        <img src="assets/images/github.svg" alt="">
        <img src="assets/images/linkedin.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

But if i add the a tag they stop showing dissapearing

```
<a href="randomsite.com">
    <img src="assets/images/gmail.svg" alt="">
</a>
```

[image]

CSS

```
.content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.contact .content img{
  max-width: 32%;
}
```

Comment: give image height, it will work.

Comment: thanks it worked. I had to add a height with px because if i add % it wasn't still showing.

Comment: If you give height with %, it takes height considering it's parent. In this case parent is `a` which is a inline element and by default it's height is 0. So its not showing. Please study about `inline, inline-block and block` level element.

Comment: Oh i see, now i know about parent's height thing, thank you bro and sure i'll keep practicing.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to give a 32% of max-width to an imagen inside a non block tag (your <a...> tag), this means that if your  tag has no size the image contained on it will have a max width of 32% of zero.

So... you need to asign width to your link tag and then adjust de image inside.

Images without link:

```
.contact .content > img{
  max-width: 32%;
}
```

Links and their images:

```
.contact .content a {
  width: 32%; /* <--Line added on edit */
  max-width: 32%;
  display: block;
}
.contact .content a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```css
.content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.contact .content > img {
  max-width: 32%;
  height: auto;
}
.contact .content a {
  width: 32%; /* <--Line added on edit */
  max-width: 32%;
  display: block;
}
.contact .content a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact" id="contact">
    <div class="content">
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdns.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2018/240/iconmonstr-gmail-1.png" alt=""></a>
        <img src="https://cdns.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2012/240/iconmonstr-github-1.png" alt="">
        <img src="https://cdns.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2012/240/iconmonstr-linkedin-3.png" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: this isn't working me. The images aren't showing. But if i give height a pixel value it shows.

Comment: @DiegoDonoso I have added a Test to my reply. I dont have your images on svg but i'm pretty sure it have to work

Comment: see bro https://ibb.co/9Yst4J7 , it aint working for me. This is my footer https://pastebin.com/DcpitXLa

Comment: @DiegoDonoso... i revisited mi answer and try it with svg files and you were right, i missed a detail.
Check again and take a close look to "<--Line added on edit". With this solution you will not have to asign a fixed heigth. I hope I hit the nail on the head this time, if dont... please let me know and i will try again (ya es algo personal :D ).